# Items in GridView lost its state when it when they are out of the viewport

Tags: flutter, gridview, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am beginner in flutter. I want to create a 8x2 gridview with button(custom  button widget).But Items in GridView lost its state when it when they are out of the viewport.I also tried SilverGrid.There also the same proplem.Here is my code snippet. The selected status of SoundCard is lost its state when i scroll down and return to top of SoundCard.I enclosed the sample picture [here](http://vgifbot.online/gif/CgACAgUAAxkBAAEtmX9fu4j0x_omMMC7XnnfuzIbjGvMYQACTAMAAog74FVQJo16J3uIfR4E_1606125838.92.gif).

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:relax/constants.dart';
    import 'package:relax/soundcard.dart';
    
    class Index extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _IndexState createState() => _IndexState();
    }
    class _IndexState extends State<Index> {
     bool playState = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Color(0xFF55b9f3),
        child: GridView.count(
          primary: false,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          crossAxisSpacing: 40,
          mainAxisSpacing: 40,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'rain',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'summernight',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'water',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'wind',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'thunderstorm',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'forest',
             
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'leaves',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'fireplace',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'waterstream',
            
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'seaside',
             
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'brownnoise',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'coffeeshop',
             
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'fan',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'pinknoise',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'whitenoise',
              
            ),
            SoundCard(
              assetName: 'train',
             
            ),
          ],
        )
      
        );
  }
}
```

The SoundCard is like button .When i scroll and return to the top, the selected status of SoundCard button is lost its selected state.Can any one help me out of this?

Comment: can you show us the code, where when you pressed the button it is selected?

Comment: Thank You !, I solved this by adding ` AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` with my SoundCard Widget

Comment: @ARUNBALAJI please add your solution as an answer and accept it so people with similar issues can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure the state is maintained even after navigating off the screen, add a mixin called **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin** to the State and override the **wantKeepAlive** getter as such:

```
class _IndexState extends State<Index> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
{
    @override
    bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the above problem by adding `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` with my SounCard.
In brief
When we develop our apps, our design usually has a Home screen with a multi Tab bar or Page view. The problem we have is that when we change pages, the state of the previous page would be lost. It was inconvenient.

It is solved by below method.

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const Page({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}
class _PageState extends State<Page> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  int _value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); /// Remember to add this line!!!
   ...
   ...
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Remember to add " **super.build(context);** "